# Does Silverlight support Outlook Addin(Javascript API)?

Tags: silverlight, outlook-addin, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

We are trying to integrate Silverlight components in Outlook task panel which is developed by Outlook Javascript API. However when mailapp(task panel) loaded, it appears error and it prompts the Silverlight addin failed to run and please check security settings in “Internet Options”. I also tried adding website URL into IE trusted sites list, but this error remains. But I also notice that it works fine in IE browsers.

I know the mailapp (task panel) initials a web browser (IE kernel) in embedded mode. But I really want to confirm whether Silverlight is supported or NOT in MailApp？ If it's supported, how should I do?

Anyone gives me the right answer will save my life. Thanks in advance.

[It prompts security settings conflicted in MailApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfSpO.jpg)

[But it works fine in a separate IE browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yjWk.jpg)